# Speedup address concatenation from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 30 columns and several million rows. A subset of those columns are address items, e.g.

```
        premises  address_line_1  address_line_2  locality  region  postal_code         country  
              77  Compton Street             NaN  Bradford     NaN      BD4 9NE  United Kingdom  
4 Fourfields Way       New Arley             NaN  Coventry     NaN      CV7 8PX  United Kingdom
```

I want to concatenate those fields into a single field and I am using the following:

```
items = ['premises', 'address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 
         'locality', 'region', 'postal_code', 'country']
df[items].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

which produces the expected output but it is very slow:

```
'77, Compton Street, Bradford, BD4 9NE, United Kingdom'
'4 Fourfields Way, New Arley, Coventry, CV7 8PX, United Kingdom'
```

Any suggestions on how to **speed this operation up**?

Note that fields might be numeric, e.g. `premises 77`, and I need to drop NaNs to avoid someting like `'...Bradford, NaN, BD4 9NE,...'`

The types of the dataframe are:

```
premises          object
address_line_1    object
address_line_2    object
locality          object
region            object
postal_code       object
country           object
dtype: object
```

and the `%prun -l 10 ds[items].loc[0:1000,:]` is:

```
 531745 function calls (524476 primitive calls) in 0.653 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 321 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2709    0.086    0.000    0.207    0.000 arrayprint.py:543(fillFormat)
        2    0.083    0.042    0.083    0.042 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis0_object_object}
     8138    0.032    0.000    0.032    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
    63629    0.018    0.000    0.035    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
     9638    0.018    0.000    0.024    0.000 arrayprint.py:628(_digits)
20852/20851    0.012    0.000    0.014    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
      916    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
     5418    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 numeric.py:2676(geterr)
     5418    0.010    0.000    0.028    0.000 numeric.py:2576(seterr)
      903    0.009    0.000    0.267    0.000 arrayprint.py:237(_array2string)
```

### The ugly but fast alternative

```
address = (df['address.premises'].astype(str) + ', ' + 
           df['address.address_line_1'].astype(str) + ', ' +
           df['address.address_line_2'].astype(str) + ', ' + 
           df['address.locality'].astype(str) + ', ' +
           df['address.region'].astype(str) + ', ' +  
           df['address.postal_code'].astype(str) + ', ' + 
           df['address.country'].astype(str))
```

followed by literal `nan` replacement:

```
address.apply(lambda x: x.replace(', nan','').replace('nan, ','').replace(',,',','))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably accept some further optimization, but should produce the same result if you do not have your separator in any of the fields listed in items, and it is much faster.

```
df[items[0]].fillna('').astype(str).str.cat(others=[df[item].fillna('').astype(str) for item in items[1:]], sep=',').str.replace(',,+', ',').str.strip(',').replace('',np.nan)
```

For a much smaller, around 100,000 line dataframe, this gave me

```
%timeit df[items[0]].fillna('').astype(str).str.cat(others=[df[item].fillna('').astype(str) for item in items[1:]], sep=',').str.replace(',,+', ',').str.strip(',').replace('',np.nan)
1 loop, best of 3: 389 ms per loop
```

compared to

```
%timeit df[items].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min per loop
```

**Edit:**

For better readability, this could be rewritten in two lines as

```
address = [df[item].fillna('').astype(str) for item in items]
address[0].str.cat(address[1:], sep=',').str.replace(',,+', ',').str.strip(',')
```

`.replace('', np.nan)` removed due to an apparent willingness to have empty strings as shown in the ugly but fast edit.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is basically a programmatic approach to my **fast but ugly**, although a bit less readable.

Comment: Answered before I saw that edit, and yeah, pretty much. Readability can be improved with some line breaks/intermediate steps, as used in your fast but ugly approach. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Apply is very slow and unnecessary for concatenation. Use simple concatenation logic:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)    

df['final_address'] = df['premises'].astype(str) + ' ' + \
df['address_line_1'].astype(str) + ' '  + df['address_line_2'].astype(str) \
+ ' '+ df['locality'].astype(str) + ' '+ df['region'].astype(str) + ' '+ ' '+\ 
df['postal_code'].astype(str) + ' '+ ' '+ df['country'].astype(str)
```